# Persisting state of Firebase data

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

On the start of my app I want to load data from Firebase and if there is no internet connection I want to use the persisted data. Is this possible with Firebase? If there is internet it should just update the data if not it should use the old data.

If it's not possible is there anything else to do this with? Or a better advice?

Maybe this is already the case I am not sure I never worked with Firebase yet but I wanted to know this before starting working with it.

Comment: It's easier for folks to help if you've tried to get something working and show us your code. In principle, what you're saying is possible. You just have to make sure that you're keeping a copy of the data in some kind of local persistent storage (so that you try to request firebase first, if it fails, then load from local storage). This has nothing to do with react/redux so far.

Comment: Yes sorry but I didn't know where to start. I was looking into middlewares on the redux page and they seem to be cached so I was wondering if it would be possible using a Firebase middleware.

Comment: All Firebase SDKs handle intermittent connectivity loss: they cache the data in memory and queue writes. Disk persistence is available for native mobile clients in Android and iOS. It is not available for JavaScript clients.